# I need to block PUT request to server using apache2.2

Tags: tomcat, server, apache2, put

Basically request is like `http://<IP>/server/elements/planning?xyz` where it updating my details which don't want to edit. How do I block that? Any suggestion is most welcome. I tried to add be below string in `/sites-available/default` but it blocks all the string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/server/elements/planning?customerid="     [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PUT) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

SO please help me. I am new to apache2 so please be specific where to add.